# MATLAB - Linear Programming

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

It is a linear programming problem that is trying to minimize. Looked at many examples, but none to similar to this one. Specifically confused on how to use `inf()` and `zero()` for the bounds.

I have many of the constraints already like:

```
c = [6, 8, -6, -1]
A = [];
B = [];
Aeq = [9, 3, -1, -1; 17, 1, 0, -2; 4, -5, 6, 1];
beq = [30, -20, 6.7]
```

but very confused on the rest of it!

Comment: What's wrong with the [docs](https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html)? You saw ```lb``` and ```ub```? And your current approach is wrong too if A_eq really is used for A_eq.

Comment: A = [9, 3, -1, -1; 17, 1, 0, -2; 4, -5, 6, 1];

B = [30, -20, 6.7];

Aeq = [];

beq = [];      I still do not know how to use the bounds. Sorry, I am new to linear programming and matlab

Comment: It's described in the docs, including examples. ????? Everything is covered, except maybe for [inf](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/infinity-and-nan.html) (which can be negated too).

Comment: Are you able to solve part 1? If so, please include the solution in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
vC = [6; 8; -6; -1];
mA = [9, 3, -1, -1; -17, -1, 0, 2];
vB = [30; 20];
mAEq = [4, -5, 6, 1];
vBEq = [6.7];
vL = [-3; 6.5; -inf; -inf];
vU = [15; inf; -2; inf];

vX = linprog(vC , mA, vB, mAEq, vBEq, vL, vU);
disp(['Optimal Solution - ', num2str(vX.')]);
disp(['Objective Value - ', num2str(vC.' * vX)]);

Optimal solution found.

Optimal Solution - 3.036          6.5           -2       39.056
Objective Value - 43.16
```

You have to make the 2nd inequality to the form `<=`.
The rest is straight forward.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to completely solve a question that is clearly a homework. There are already a lot of examples available on the internet.

Comment: I'm not a moral police. Someone asked question I try to assist. I don't think it deserves `-1`.